# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for $ in strict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I call a javascript file which uses javascript in strict mode. Normally the error mentioned in the title occurs when function doesn't pass the $ to the function but I pass it:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    // Many functions here

    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            // bla bla
        }
    );

}($));
```

There are two other JS files in my system which work the same way with no problem. Merging files might help my business model but I first want to understand the technical problem before the easy solution.

Thank you by now.

Comment: If `$` is also undefined *outside* the function, then it won't work. That's what you need to check. (Also that error has nothing at all to do with strict mode.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I include jquery before this code. ...but I found the solution. I'll note it as the answer now.

Comment: The correct answer would be to just use the proper DOM ready function, as noted in the [documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/#use-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `jQuery` instance to the IIFE. If there are other libraries on the page that uses `$` symbol using `$` in noConflict will not work as expected(where `$` is expected as the other library handle).

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // bla bla
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the answer. noConflict() solves the problem:

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Putting in the beginning of the script solved the problem related with $.

Comment: I'm glad this worked, but if it did then that means *some other script did the same thing*. You may find that it did it for a reason.